# Making a sticky header stick to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed to make a dropdown for a website I am designing and I'm a bit stuck on the sticky header part..

My header has the sticky effect however when i scroll down the header does not stick to the top of the page. It always maintains a margin of 80px from the top as i mentioned in the CSS.

How can i make the header stick to the TOP when i scroll and when i scroll back to the top of the page it should retain its original position. Hope i have made myself clear.

Just pasting my CSS as the HTML is too lengthy in the fiddle.

```
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index:9998;
    position:relative;
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/5GqYh/) for a DEMO I have created.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear. I want the top:80px to be there initially. I only want the header to stick to the top while scrolling. [EXAMPLE](http://www.flipkart.com/)

Comment: I believe this is only possible with javascript (jQuery)

Comment: it works sticky in my firefox. Is that 80px top margin normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5GqYh/2/)**

**Changes in CSS:**

```
#nav {
position:fixed;
top:-40px;
}
```

Comment: Nathan i guess i did not clear myself enough. I want the starting position to be 80px from the top. Only when i scroll the page i want the header to stick to the top

Comment: Agreed Fags and MarsOne

Comment: Here is your solution - @MarsOne http://jsfiddle.net/XyVAG/9/ - I hope this is what you want.

Comment: But you have to change your class and id names according to the script names. - @MarsOne

Comment: I made some changes but it only works once for me. WHen i scroll back to the top the effect stops.http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/5GqYh/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have some conflicting styles you need to get rid of:

http://jsfiddle.net/5GqYh/4/

Firstly, you had `top` inline your header, so I set it to 0.

I also adjust the top margin on your menu, that was also pushing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Remove this from ur css to make the header stick to the top.

   `#nav {
    ..
    margin:40px auto;
    ..
   }`

2.css style for header - position:relative will do instead of position:fixed.

3.Put the content div inside another div and create a scrollbar only for that div. In that way, your header will always stick to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .sticky class on your CSS that makes the element's position fixed, then you can easily detect if the user scrolled enough to make it stick to the top, at which point you add the .sticky class to the element. Of course when the user scrolls all the way back you should remove the class. Example:

```
function stick() { 
   var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(stickyNavTop > scrollTop) {
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky'); 
   } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
   }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
   stick();
});
```